# javascript adding items to global array in nested function, changes are not reflected outside using gmail api

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, gmail-api

So i have this code

```
  function addEmail(e){
      emails.push(e);
  }
  var emails = new Array;

  function getMessage( messages, callback ) {

      var get = function(len){


        //console.log(messages[len].id);
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
            'userId': 'me',
            'id': messages[len].id
          });
        request.execute(function(response){
            var e = parseMessages(response)
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
            addEmail(e);    

        });
        len++;

        if(len<messages.length){
            console.log(emails.length);
            get(len);
        }
        else{
            console.log(emails.length);
            process(emails);
        }

      }
      get(0);


  };
```

when i am trying to access the emails array outside the method getMessage it is empty. 
this line of code "console.log(emails.length);" always prints 0,
however when i put this line of code inside get method, it shows values are being added to the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > when i am trying to access the emails array outside the method getMessage it is empty. this line of code "console.log(emails.length);" always prints 0

Timing!

I'm pretty sure, you wanted to build this:

```
function getMessage( messages, callback ) {
    var emails = [];
    get(0);

    function get(index){
        if(index === messages.length){
            return callback(emails);
        }

        //console.log(messages[index].id);
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
            'userId': 'me',
            'id': messages[index].id
        });

        request.execute(function(response){
            var e = parseMessages(response)
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
            emails.push(e);
            get(index+1);
        });
    }
}


getMessage( someMessages, function(emails){
    console.log(emails);
})
```

or paralell:

```
function getMessage( messages, callback ) {
    function done(){
        if(--pending) return;   //still work left
        callback(emails);
    }

    var pending = 1, 
        emails = Array(messages.length);

    messages.forEach(function(msg, i){
        ++pending;

        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
            'userId': 'me',
            'id': msg.id
        });

        request.execute(function(response){
            emails[i] = parseMessages(response);
            done();
        });
    });

    done();
}
```

- not tested